# Have we ever seen Bruce Wayne getting facial re-constructive surgery?

Tags: dc, batman, dc-animated-universe

As Batman, [Bruce](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batman_(Bruce_Wayne)) takes a serious whoopin' regularly enough. In some canons his cowl probably offers some protection but as any UFC fighter's face will tell you, a career in fist fights will inevitably cause you some disfiguring injuries.

Also, Batman often fights the likes of [Bane](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Bane), [Clayface](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Clayface_(Basil_Karlo)) and [Killer Croc](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Killer_Croc), super powered villains that pack a stronger punch than any *normal* human.

Do we ever see Bruce getting re-constructive surgery to keep his handsome face handsome? I feel like Batman wouldn't care how he looked, but Bruce is expected to.

*I'm talking about purely cosmetic surgery here.*

Possibly related: [How does Bruce Wayne mask Batman's injuries between beatings?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84008/how-does-bruce-wayne-mask-batmans-injuries-between-beatings), but this question makes no mention of Bruce possibly going under the knife to repair any facial injuries.

Comment: This is a really weird question.. I like it.

Comment: If Batman were a real person this would be a problem. But since it's a comic book, it isn't a problem. This is like when Grant Morrison explained that nobody pumps the tires on the Batmobile.

Comment: @RaceBannon you're no fun. You could apply similar logic to every question on this site...

Comment: You can apply this line of thinking to everything. I think when you get to the point when you ask questions like this, it's because comics are no fun for you/you're too old for comics. You shouldn't ask these questions in the first place. How did Batman have time to master 127 forms of martial arts when it takes decades to master some? How does he stay the best human alive and also run a multibillion dollar business while crime fighting at night - when does he sleep? All these questions shouldn't be asked because they ruin the magic. Just take it for what it is, like you are meant to.

Comment: @RaceBannon I think you misunderstand the question. I'm asking if we ever actually see it or if it's ever referenced in some way. I'm not asking for an explanation of how his injuries heal. There's a clear difference. There's been so many Batman story arcs, I'm curious if someone has mentioned it somewhere, like Bruce had to get corrective surgery in time for an important social engagement. U get me?

Comment: There isn't. And he probably doesn't get plastic surgery. He is covered with scars. http://i.imgur.com/0cPSFBO.png

Comment: @RaceBannon _probably_ isn't an answer.

Comment: It is never mentioned in the comics. Ever. He is covered in scars, however. That's also why I wrote it as a comment, not an answer. https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/85/e5/5a/85e55ab76f0b4e4c99d5e79de13bf2f4.jpg

Comment: @RaceBannon you'll notice I included the DCAU tag also. Does your encyclopedic knowledge extend to the animated universe also?

Comment: In the animated universe, he's never shown getting plastic surgery. It's also never mentioned, referenced, or hinted at. Ever.

Comment: @RaceBannon seems like you don't understand the question. _re-constructive surgery to keep his handsome face handsome_... you keep posting pics of topless Batman, but the OP is clearly enquiring about facial scars / surgery.

Comment: @RaceBannon: Do we ever meet his dentist?

Comment: Oh they have a reference to scars on his body in *The Dark Knight Rises* too, in his presumably post-coital scene with Miranda.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I'd be mainly interested in facial damage. Bruce needs to keep his _playboy philanthropist billionaire_ image intact

Comment: @Daft: yeah totally. Maybe, because he’s Batman, he deals with it in advance. *I’m Batman. [catches criminal’s fist.] Not in the face, punk.*

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I feel as if his tough guy image would take a hit if his catchphrase was _Not in the face, punk._ :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This probably isn't what you're looking for, but it seems the answer is no.

I've performed lots of research and have been unable to find any instance of Bruce Wayne under-going facial surgery to hide or fix injuries he received while crime-fighting.